# Create two columns on the fly in mysql

Tags: mysql, datetime, sequence

I was creating two columns on the fly in a mysql query. They should look like this.

```
+------------------+
|Month    | toOrder|
+-------------------
|Nov-2014 |2014-11 |
--------------------
|Dec-2014 |2014-12 |
--------------------
|Jan-2015 |2015-01 |
--------------------
|Feb-2015 |2015-02 |
--------------------
|Mar-2015 |2015-03 |
--------------------
|Apr-2015 |2015-04 |
--------------------
|May-2015 |2015-05 |
--------------------
|Jun-2015 |2015-06 |
--------------------
|Jul-2015 |2015-07 |
--------------------
|Aug-2015 |2015-08 |
--------------------
|Sep-2015 |2015-09 |
--------------------
|Oct-2015 |2015-10 |
+------------------+
```

I am using this query

```
SELECT *
FROM    (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 11 MONTH), '%b-%Y') as Month UNION
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 10 MONTH), '%b-%Y') as Month UNION
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 9 MONTH), '%b-%Y') as Month UNION
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 8 MONTH), '%b-%Y') as Month UNION
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 7 MONTH), '%b-%Y') as Month UNION
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH), '%b-%Y') as Month UNION
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 5 MONTH), '%b-%Y') as Month UNION
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 4 MONTH), '%b-%Y') as Month UNION
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH), '%b-%Y') as Month UNION
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH), '%b-%Y') as Month UNION
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH), '%b-%Y') as Month UNION
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(now(), '%b-%Y') as Month) AS Months
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 11 MONTH), '%Y-%m') as toOrder UNION
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 10 MONTH), '%Y-%m') as toOrder UNION
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 9 MONTH), '%Y-%m') as toOrder UNION
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 8 MONTH), '%Y-%m') as toOrder UNION
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 7 MONTH), '%Y-%m') as toOrder UNION
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH), '%Y-%m') as toOrder UNION
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 5 MONTH), '%Y-%m') as toOrder UNION
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 4 MONTH), '%Y-%m') as toOrder UNION
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH), '%Y-%m') as toOrder UNION
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH), '%Y-%m') as toOrder UNION
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH), '%Y-%m') as toOrder UNION
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(now(), '%Y-%m') as toOrder) AS toOrders
ON TRUE = TRUE
```

But output that I am receiving is different of what I am expecting.

```
+------------------+
|Month    | toOrder|
+-------------------
|Nov-2014 |2014-11 |
--------------------
|Dec-2014 |2014-11 |
--------------------
|Jan-2015 |2014-11 |
--------------------
|Feb-2015 |2014-11 |
--------------------
|Mar-2015 |2014-11 |
--------------------
|Apr-2015 |2014-11 |
--------------------
|May-2015 |2014-11 |
--------------------
|Jun-2015 |2014-11 |
--------------------
|Jul-2015 |2014-11 |
--------------------
|Aug-2015 |2014-11 |
--------------------
|Sep-2015 |2014-11 |
--------------------
|Oct-2015 |2014-11 |
--------------------
|Nov-2014 |2014-12 |
--------------------
|Dec-2014 |2014-12 |
--------------------
|Jan-2015 |2014-12 |
--------------------
|Feb-2015 |2014-12 |
--------------------
|Mar-2015 |2014-12 |
--------------------
|Apr-2015 |2014-12 |
--------------------
|May-2015 |2014-12 |
--------------------
|Jun-2015 |2014-12 |
--------------------
|Jul-2015 |2014-12 |
--------------------
|Aug-2015 |2014-12 |
--------------------
|Sep-2015 |2014-12 |
--------------------
|Oct-2015 |2014-12 |
--------------------
|Nov-2014 |2015-01 |
+------------------+
```

I am using "toOrders" column in order to do an ORDER BY later with an other LEFT JOIN that I will have in the future.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. It's important here to actually ask a question.  You have two of the important elements: 1) I want this. 2) I tried this. But you don't have 3) but it produces that instead of what I want.

Comment: @Ollie thank you for your comment, I will add the 3rd element to my question to have a complete  question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing a JOIN without an ON clause. That is called a cross join, and generates all possible combinations of your output.  Something like this may generate what you want.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(Month,'%b-%Y') AS Month,
       DATE_FORMAT(Month,'%Y-%m') AS toOrder
FROM (
    SELECT DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 11 MONTH) as Month      UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 10 MONTH) as Month      UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 9 MONTH) as Month       UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 8 MONTH) as Month       UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 7 MONTH) as Month       UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH) as Month       UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 5 MONTH) as Month       UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 4 MONTH) as Month       UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH) as Month       UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH) as Month       UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) as Month       UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 0 MONTH) as Month  
 ) months
ORDER BY months.Month
```

**However** this formulation may yield strange results near the ends of months.  I would trust the following query more completely.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(month.start - INTERVAL seq.seq MONTH,'%b-%Y') AS Month,
       DATE_FORMAT(month.start - INTERVAL seq.seq MONTH,'%Y-%m') AS toOrder
FROM (
   SELECT 11 AS seq UNION ALL
   SELECT 10 UNION ALL
   SELECT  9 UNION ALL
   SELECT  8 UNION ALL
   SELECT  7 UNION ALL
   SELECT  6 UNION ALL
   SELECT  5 UNION ALL
   SELECT  4 UNION ALL
   SELECT  3 UNION ALL
   SELECT  2 UNION ALL
   SELECT  1 UNION ALL
   SELECT  0
) seq
JOIN (
   SELECT CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(CURRENT_DATE()) - 1 DAY AS start
) month 
ORDER BY seq.seq DESC
```

That's because

```
SELECT CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(CURRENT_DATE()) - 1 DAY AS start
```

does a good job of converting today's date into the first day of the present month.

Comment: thank you Ollie for your answer. The first solution I would change the order to ORDER BY toOrder and then I get order that I need. The second solution gives me the exact output that I need.

Comment: Also, with the second solution you are telling me that the query will go from today to 12 month back. Right?

Comment: You found a bug in my first solution, thanks. I would use `ORDER BY months.Month` . I've edited my answer. The second query puts out a list of twelve months *ending* with the present month.